# html/javascript code to load html pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a tabs using html and css code. The content to be displayed in each tab is placed in different html pages.
I want to load the tab content without using any API(jquery/PHP..). I want to load the html pages when user navigates to the tabs and i want to use only html/javascript to achieve this.

[Code demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/UT7irDu86SHH9sxrNh7t?p=preview)

I have tried using the below code but its not working.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>
    <script>
        w3IncludeHTML();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
..
    <div class="tab">
        <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
        <label for="tab-1">Tab1</label>
        <div class="content">
            <div w3-include-html="tab1Content.html"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You might want to try including the CSS, which sets the behaviour of the tabs. I'd also suggest fixing the `..` after your first `<body>` tag

Answer (score 1):

I used to add a iframe into div:

```
<div class="content">
    <iframe src="file.html">      
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of doing this.

1.) **iFrames**
Instead of this:

```
<div w3-include-html="tab1Content.html"></div>
```

Do this:

```
<iframe src="tab1Content.html"></iframe>
```

2.)**PHP**
If for some reasons iFrames don't work for you, you can do this in php:

```
<div class="content"><?php echo file_get_contents("tab1Content.html");?></div>
```

---